# Dynamically adding HTML form elements with Meteor

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

I'm very new to Meteor, enjoying it and am making some test apps to build my skills.

I want to add a form that allows dynamic addition of a phone number field.  The idea being that I'm adding a company into the collection/database and one company may have 0 phone numbers, another might have 3 and another might have 20.  So I want to be able to press say, a PLUS button or similar and have the input fields appear in the HTML.

I've played around with sessions a little and think they may be the key to the puzzle.

I have the following so far (for this part of the app):

My HTML template:

```
<template name="organisationAddForm">
    <h3>Add a new organisation</h3>
    <form name="addForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-1">
                <p>Name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-1">
                <input type="input" name="newOrgName" placeholder="Organisation Name">
            </div>
        </div>

            {{> addPhoneNumber}}

        <div class = "row">
         <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-1">
             <input type="submit" value="Add Organisation">
         </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

and

```
<template name="addPhoneNumber">
    <h4>Phone Numbers</h4>

    <ul>
        {{#each phoneNumber}}
            <li>Number: {{number}} </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <a href = "#" class ="add-phone"> [ Add Phone Number ]</a>
</template>
```

So far my Javascript is incomplete as I'm a bit stuck:

```
Template.addPhoneNumber.events({
  // when user clicks the Add Phone link
  'click .add-phone': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

The idea with the above is:

1- User clicks the add-phone link which will add a value to the session.
2- The each loop will be looping through the session data and re-drawing the form with however many inputs the session data tells it to draw.

I hope that makes sense and it's focused enough.

I'm not asking for anyone to write code for me, more help me with direction (is this the right direction?) and suggestions on how to go about it.  I want to learn programming and be better at this and am happy to do the hard yards.  This has just got me stuck, so here I am.  :-)

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Rob

Comment: You should be able to take the code right out of the default ToDo list application. Instead of adding a task, you're adding a phone number to a company (`{name:'someCompany',phoneNumbers:[]}`). As far as a dynamic form, that will look just like the ToDo list example.

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  So you're suggesting to add the form data into a temp collection whilst the user inputs the data?  That way manipulating the temp collection as they enter data, then saving from the temp collection to a permanent collection on save?

Comment: You could do it via temp collection, but you can also just add a new barebones company to your actual collection when the user clicks add new company. The barebones company won't have any default phone numbers, just an empty array. As the user adds phone numbers, that property and form is updated on the fly.

Comment: That's a great idea.  As I say I'm new so learning what structure to use and when is a challenge.  Like knowing there's a better way but not being sure of what it is.  Appreciate that answer.